# gunicorn incompatible with python 3.8

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, gunicorn

As part of learning python, **using Conda** I am trying to do create a virtual environment with spyder, flask and gunicorn but stuck due to compatibility issues with gunicorn.
Can anyone check below and suggest the way forward.

1. Created a virtual environment with python 3.9 and activated it
2. Installed flask and spyder - Went fine.
3. Tried installing gunicorn using `conda install -c phumke gunicorn`, but it failed with below error.

   ```
   Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
   Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
   Solving environment: |
   Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
   This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort./
   failed

   UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

   Specifications:

   - gunicorn -> python=3.5

   Your python: python=3.8

   If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for. When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify that.
   ```
4. So I removed this virtual environment and recreated it with python version 3.5 And then tried installing spyder again. But now spyder is failing as below.

   ```
    ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(700): An error occurred while installing package                 
    'defaults::ipykernel-4.10.0-py35_0'.
    Rolling back transaction: done

    LinkError: post-link script failed for package defaults::ipykernel-4.10.0-py35_0
   ```

I'm doing all this on Anaconda prompt on a Windows machine. Can anyone help on how to fix this?

Comment: Gunicorn is not compatible with Windows.

Comment: @KlausD. - Thanks for the reply. In that case, can you suggest how to use gunicorn? Also I have a basic question (seems I'm missing some fundamentals).
Initially, I installed Python and also Anaconda . When I imported basic packages like pandas using python on command prompt, It was not reflectng in Spyder. Then I realised that my python installation is different from Spyder installation. 
After that, I uninstalled python and using only Spyder. Is this correct way? If not, how to install packages in python and get them reflected in spyder?

Comment: About gunicorn: Run it in a UNIX environment (natively, in a VM or a Docker container). About the other stuff: That would be a new question.

Comment: @KlausD. - I am doing a course on Udemy and I was told gunicorn is available on windows for sure. Am I missing something here?